# Merging two dataframes on multiple columns

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have two dataframes that I am trying to merge :

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(ID=sample(letters[1:6],10,replace=TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(
  ID1 = letters[1:2],
  ID2 = letters[3:4],
  ID3 = letters[5:6],
  V1 = c(23.32,21.24),
  V2 = c(45.32,47.21)
)
```

Post merging, I want my `df1` to contain the columns `V1` and `V2` along with `ID`. I have tried using `merge`, `left_join` and `inner_join` (from `dplyr`) but can't figure out how to use the `by` argument. The `ID` column from `df1` could exist in any of the three columns (`ID1`, `ID2` and `ID3`) of `df2`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reshape in long format first, then join:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>% 
  gather(IDnr, ID, 1:3) %>% 
  left_join(df1, ., by = 'ID')

# alternative:
df1 %>% 
  left_join(., df2 %>% gather(IDnr, ID, 1:3), by = 'ID')
```

The result:

```
   ID    V1    V2 IDnr
1   d 21.24 47.21  ID2
2   e 23.32 45.32  ID3
3   f 21.24 47.21  ID3
4   d 21.24 47.21  ID2
5   f 21.24 47.21  ID3
6   c 23.32 45.32  ID2
7   a 23.32 45.32  ID1
8   e 23.32 45.32  ID3
9   a 23.32 45.32  ID1
10  d 21.24 47.21  ID2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `by` argument is used to specify the ID columns you want to join on assuming they are named differently for the left & right tables (if its the same name then it will automatically choose).

However, I have a way to simplify what you want to do. First, why not reshape `df2` to only have 1 single ID column (assumption that the ID is unique within all 3 columns). You can do this by creating 3 separate dfs and then union together using `bind_rows`.

Now that it is reshaped, you can do a right join. `df1` is on the right side of the join and all the records in `df1` will remain whether or not there is a match with `df2` (otherwise `V1` and `V2` will be NULL i.e. `NA`).

With the sample data provided from `df1`, the results would be unexpected because each ID is repeated and not unique (so I have redefined `df1` to have unique IDs only). If the IDs are not unique, you can group the results by ID and do an aggregation prior to doing the join.

```r
set.seed(123)
#df1 <- data.frame(ID=sample(letters[1:6],10,replace=TRUE)) #This one has repeated IDs
df1 <- data.frame(ID=letters[1:6])
df2 <- data.frame(
  ID1 = letters[1:2],
  ID2 = letters[3:4],
  ID3 = letters[5:6],
  V1 = c(23.32,21.24),
  V2 = c(45.32,47.21)
)

library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.4.2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- bind_rows(df2 %>% select(ID=ID1, V1, V2),
                df2 %>% select(ID=ID2, V1, V2),
                df2 %>% select(ID=ID3, V1, V2)) %>% 
      right_join(df1)
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector

#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector

#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector
#> Joining, by = "ID"
#> Warning: Column `ID` joining character vector and factor, coercing into
#> character vector
df
#>   ID    V1    V2
#> 1  a 23.32 45.32
#> 2  b 21.24 47.21
#> 3  c 23.32 45.32
#> 4  d 21.24 47.21
#> 5  e 23.32 45.32
#> 6  f 21.24 47.21
```